# Remove AM and PM on Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using Eonasdan Bootstrap 3 Datetimepciker. Here I don't wnat to display the  AM and PM in screen. How can I remove this in screen?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use this code by passing required format in format option you can achieve 12 hr format

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format: 'HH:mm'});
```

Comment: If you need to keep the date you can use `DD-MM-YY HH:mm`.

Answer (score 0):

not **HH** format instead of use **hh** (small)

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format: 'hh:mm'});
```

otherwise hide **am/pm on show** event called

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format: 'LT'}).on('dp.show', function(event) {
              $(".bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget").find('.btn[data-action="togglePeriod"]').hide();
});
```